# If statement for dataframe

Tags: r, if-statement

I have the following sample data:

```
A = data.frame( x=c('x','x','y','y','z','z'), j=c(1,1,1,2,2,3)   )
A$z[A$x=="x"]=1
A$z[A$x=="y"]=1
A$z[is.na(A$z)]=0
```

And I would like to create a new column `"Test"` using column `"z"` equal to 1 as condition and take value of column `"x"`.

I use the following statement but there is a warning message

```
if(A$z==1)A$Test=A$z
```

> Warning message:
>   In if (A$z == 1) A$Test = A$z :
>     the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

How can I correct this?

Comment: `I am the following sample data` - nice to meet you, `A` ;-)

Comment: A[ "Test" ] <- ifelse( A$z == 1, A$x, 9 )

Comment: Thanks @ vaettchen, but the column return number instead of the exact value of column "x"

Comment: `idx <- A$z == 1; A$Test[idx] <- as.character(A$x[idx])`?

Comment: This is because your column x is a factor. For the sample data you can get around this with `A[ "Test" ] <- ifelse( A$z == 1, as.character( A$x ), 9 )`. for your real data, check with `str( A )` what data type you have.

Answer (score 3):

We can also do

```
A$Test <- NA^(A$z!=1)*A$z
```

Comment: I think it's an interesting convention that the team of R developers has chosen by defining `NA^0` as `1`. The way I see it, it's not mathematically rigorous (I would rather expect `NaN`), but for programming purposes and "code golfing" it's definitely a nice feature.

Comment: @RHertel It's a nice feature otherwise, we have to use `ifelse` in a lot of situations.

Answer (score 1):

Create the `test` variable as part of the data frame and use `ifelse()` to add the appropriate values.  Consider:

```
A$Test = ifelse(A$z==1, A$z, NA)
```